# Web API parameter binding not working

Tags: asp.net-web-api, model-binding, asp.net-web-api2

I have two entity classes `Donor` and `User`. Donor is subclass of User as given below

```
public abstract class User {
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    ...
}    

public class Donor : User {
    public string AlternateMobileNumber { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

A web api controller action shown below receives `POST` request with JSON data in the body

```
public class DonorsController : ApiController  {

    //POST: api/Donors/EditDonor
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage EditDonor([FromBody] Donor donor) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Here is how the post request looks like

```
POST http://localhost:xxxxx/Donor/api/Donors/EditDonor HTTP/1.1
Content-Length: 477
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Accept: */*
...

{"Id":12,"UserId":"donor9@abc.com","FirstName":"firstname9c","MiddleName":"M","LastName":"lastname9","Gender":"Male","MobileNumber":"7777777777","BloodGroup":"A+ve","OfficeLocality":{"Id":2,"Name":"Malad"},"ResidenceLocality":{"Id":2,"Name":"Malad"},"Organization":"organization9","Designation":"designation9","TimesDonated":1,"DateLastDonated":"Mon Dec 01 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2014","LastDonatedAt":"Hosp 1","IsSDPDonor":false,"IsIntrestedDonor":false,"Comments":"Some Comment"}
```

The issue is that the **Donor** object is empty (not null but empty, without values applied to properties of Donor).

If I change **Donor** object and use a **Data Transfer Object (DonorDO)** with the same properties but without any inheritance, then the properties are correctly populated in that Data object. For example the Donor Data Object is like below.

```
//Plain Data Transfer Object without inheritance
public class DonorDO {
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string AlternateMobileNumber { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Why does **DonorDO** get its property values bound correctly, while the **Donor** Entity object remains empty with none of the properties bound. Is it related to inheritance or some other issue.

Comment: Maybe the problem is in your Json format. Try it with some simple Json that contains only Id and AlternateMobileNumber properties? By the way you can remove FromBody attribute because Donor is not a primitive type so it automatically fetched from body

Comment: Thanks for pointing out about FromBody. I tried as you suggested to send only a couple of fields instead of the full JSON, but the Donor object's property values are all null or default. None of the values from input JSON get applied on the Donor object.

Comment: Where you able to resolve this?

Comment: @jarz I used the DonorDO object in the end. I don't remember why the data object worked, and not the Entity object.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that you are POSTing to "http: // localhost : xxxxx/Donor/api/Donors/EditDonor" which is wrong, you need to POST to "http: // localhost : xxxxx/api/Donors" (you need to POST to the controller base address only, and controller name should be after "api" not before).

This code is 100% working :

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;

//[Authorize]
public class DonorsController : ApiController
{

    [HttpGet]
    public Donor Get(int id)
    {
        return new Donor
        {
            Id = id,
            AlternateMobileNumber = "0000",
        };
    }

    //POST: api/Donors/EditDonor
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage EditDonor([FromBody] Donor donor)
    {
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
}

public abstract class User
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
}

public class Donor : User
{
    public string AlternateMobileNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Now, using fiddler I called this method as you can see in the bellow image, and on the controller side you can see the passed donor argument.

[image: Fiddler POST request/parameters]

[image: Visual Studio 2013 POST method Debug]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but I am using virtual directory /Donor. So my POST url is correct. There is a base website www.somewebsite.org, and my application runs as a separate application with /Donor virtual directory, that is, using url www.somewebsite.com/donor. I have other paths like http://localhost:xxxxx/Donor/api/Donors/SearchDonor working correctly, using the default parameter and model binding.

Comment: No problem, change the url in the fiddler url and try the code.